# Comparing 2 values of same variable in single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-comparison

I have a data frame as follow:

```
Obs. ID   Name type
  1) 123  abc  duplicate
  2) 123  abc  duplicate
  3) 145  abc  abc
  4) 156  abc  duplicate
  5) 156  abc  duplicate
```

if ID is same, like in obs. 1 and 2 or 4 and 5 then I want to create a new variable type=duplicate else type=vaule in Name variable(i.e abc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set the values according to the result:

```
df['type'] = np.where(df.duplicated('ID', False), 'Duplicate', 'Single')
```

---

```
print(df)

  Obs.   ID Name       type
0   1)  123  abc  Duplicate
1   2)  123  abc  Duplicate
2   3)  145  abc     Single
3   4)  156  abc  Duplicate
4   5)  156  abc  Duplicate
```

---

For the **update**, you just need a simple tweek:

```
df['type'] = np.where(~df.duplicated('ID', False), df.Name, 'Duplicate')

print(df)

  Obs.   ID Name       type
0   1)  123  abc  Duplicate
1   2)  123  abc  Duplicate
2   3)  145  abc        abc
3   4)  156  abc  Duplicate
4   5)  156  abc  Duplicate
```

Comment: could you tell me how to assign value of Name variable in TYPE column when ID is NOT Duplicate(i.e. type=single).

Comment: But tha's a different question overall right @karan ?

Comment: As a future reference @karan , note that it is not well seen to *change* questions. It will invalidate some of the answers, and make it look like they're not properly answering the question

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Dup'] = df.ID.duplicated(keep=False).map({True: 'dup', False: 'single'})

df
  Obs.   ID Name     Dup
0   1)  123  abc     dup
1   2)  123  abc     dup
2   3)  145  abc  single
3   4)  156  abc     dup
4   5)  156  abc     dup
```

Comment: could you tell me how to assign value of Name variable in TYPE column when ID is NOT Duplicate(i.e. if type=single then type=abc)